# New cluster creation using Cloudera Director

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera, cloudera-director

Getting the following error while trying to create a new cluster using Cloudera Director. Any advice?

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-227 cloudera-director-1.0.0]$ ./bin/cloudera-director bootstrap-remote   aws.reference.conf --lp.remote.hostAndPort=127.0.0.1:7189
Process logs can be found at /home/ec2-user/cloudera/cloudera-director-1.0.0/logs/application.log
Cloudera Director 1.0.0 initializing ...
Configuration file passes all validation checks.
Creating a new environment ...
>> POST http://127.0.0.1:7189/api/v1/environments
<< 401 Unauthorized
Unexpected internal error (see logs): HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Pragma: no-cache, X-Frame-Options: DENY, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=j0ii441ungs61o1ivobib7zn2;Path=/, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Server: Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)]
```

Comment: Apparently it is issue Cloudera knows. So, will be waiting on them to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Cloudera Director Server (which currently has known issues). In the meantime, you can still get the cluster running with Cloudera Director without the server part.

The command is 
./bin/cloudera-director bootstrap aws.simple.conf  (simple config)
   -OR-
./bin/cloudera-director bootstrap aws.reference.conf  (advanced config)

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the username and password for the Director server when using the bootstrap-remote command, for example:

```
... --lp.remote.username=admin --lp.remote.password=admin ...
```

This should have been included in our docs; we're working on that. (I work for Cloudera.)

Feel free to also post questions to community.cloudera.com.